# Parsing a JSON object in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-studio

I am trying to parse a single JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
  "message":"Request Successful",
  "data":{
    "id":"g8nEDt",
    "name":"Twins Bazil Twins",
    "nameDisplay":"Twins Bazil Twins",
    "abv":"6.75",
    "isOrganic":"N",
    "description":"Beers",
    }
  },
  "status":"success"
}
```

This is the code that I am using.

```
public class randomBeer  extends Activity {
TextView name1;
TextView description1;
TextView abv1;
TextView ibu1;
Button Btngetdata;

//URL to get JSON Array
    private static String urlRandom = "http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/beer/random?key=mykey";

//JSON Node Names
private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String TAG_ABV = "abv";
private static final String TAG_IBU = "ibu";

JSONObject data = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.randombeer);
    Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
    Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new JSONParse().execute();

        }
    });

}

private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        description1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.description);
        abv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.abv);
        ibu1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ibu);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(randomBeer.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urlRandom);
        return json;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            // Getting JSON Array
            data= json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(0);

            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

            String ibu;

            if(c.has("ibu")) {
                ibu = c.getString(TAG_IBU);
            } else {
                ibu = "No ibu value";
            }

            String abv;

            if(c.has("abv")) {
                abv = c.getString(TAG_ABV);
            } else {
                abv = "No abv value";
            }

            String description;

            if(c.has("description")) {
                description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
            } else {
                description = "No description available";
            }


            //Set JSON Data in TextView
            name1.setText(name);
            description1.setText(description);
            abv1.setText(abv);
            ibu1.setText(ibu);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

}
```

The problem is that it is trying to get an array but I just need and object.
How can I transform this code so it gets the object instead of trying to get an array?

I tried to change

```
data = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
```

to

```
data = json.getJSONObject(TAG_DATA);
```

but then on the line

```
JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(0);
```

I get an Error:

> (87, 51) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to
>   String.

Comment: Your sample "data" is also JSONObject, not JSONArray. Array must have [...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
data= json.getJSONObject(TAG_DATA);
```

instead of

```
data= json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
```

in onPostExecute. It now has

```
  "data":{
    "id":"g8nEDt",
    "name":"Twins Bazil Twins",
    "nameDisplay":"Twins Bazil Twins",
    "abv":"6.75",
    "isOrganic":"N",
    "description":"Beers",
    }
```

in it. To get i.e. the "name" use

```
 String name = data.getString("name");
```

**IN ADDITION:**

Make sure to execute **HttpGet** instead of HttpPost when using this link

```
http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/beer/random?key=mykey
```

Comment: Done. Now I get this error when I run my app: com.javapapers.android.jsonparsing W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for data

Comment: are you sure that your json looks like shown above? @WardP

Comment: Yes I am sure. The url always gives back a random beer from the api. This an example: {
  "message":"Request Successful",
  "data":{
    "id":"WYLmep",
    "name":"Hasser\u00f6der Premium Pils",
    "nameDisplay":"Hasser\u00f6der Premium Pils",
    "isOrganic":"N",
    "status":"verified",
    "statusDisplay":"Verified",
    "createDate":"2012-08-12 12:22:58",
    "updateDate":"2012-08-17 18:34:09"
  },
  "status":"success"
}

Comment: In which line does this error occur? Have you debugged it? @WardP

Comment: It happens on this line: data= json.getJSONObject(TAG_DATA);

Comment: Try json.toString() in onPostExecute and see what it is. @WardP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88429/discussion-between-wardp-and-burn).

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
        // Getting JSON Array 
        data= json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
        JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(0);
```

with:

```
        // Getting JSON Object 
        data= json.getJSONObject(TAG_DATA);
```

Also, replace all "c" variable usages with "data".

Comment: Done. Now I get this error when I run my app: com.javapapers.android.jsonparsing W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for data

Comment: OK, assuming that your data model says the `data` property is optional, then you first need to check if the `data` property exists (via `json.has(TAG_DATA)`) before calling `getJSONObject()`, and then do the right thing. See your other code that is already using `has()`.

Comment: But it doesn't make sense that it would not have data since it should give that value every time.

Comment: You need to either set breakpoints to see what your actual data is, and/or you should log the data (`JSONObject.toString()` might help there). This is all part of the programming experience :-). In any case, you should always try to bullet-proof your code so that anything that "should never happen" (but happens anyway) will not cause you to crash. The world is not a perfect place.